# Flash only uncategorized messages in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to display [flashed messages](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/flashing/) with the 'error' category in one section, and uncategorized messages in another section.  If I just ask for messages `with_categories=False`, I get messages with the 'error' category as well.  Preferably, I don't want to have to add a category to all my messages.  How do I get all uncategorized messages?

```
flash('You did something wrong', 'error')
flash('Hello')
```

```html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=false) %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=['error']) %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Outputs

```
You did something wrong
Hello
You did something wrong
```

I expect

```
Hello
You did something wrong
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All messages have the default category `'message'`.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/helpers.py#L342)  Get those messages, then get your other messages.

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=['message']) %}
```